# How to change date from “yyyy-mm-dd” to “mm/dd/yyyy” in Python?

Tags: python, date, formatting

I have a column in my Excel file (before importing into IDE with read_csv) with dates that begin as string type with the format of “yyyy-mm-dd” and I need to change that entire column to date type with format of “mm/dd/yyyy” as I’m importing it as a data frame in Python with Pandas.

Also, it would be great if the format could be where if the month and/or day is a single digit, then it comes out like “1/4/2021”. But if one or both are plural, then it comes out as “1/12/2021” or “10/8/2021” or “11/16/2020”.

I currently have this code:

```
df = df.df.strptime(“Date”, “%Y-%m-%d”).strftime(“%m/%d/%Y”)
```

But the IDE is saying there’s a syntax error. And I’m not sure if this is close to correct in terms of making sure the entire column is being changed.

Comment: Could you provide code please?

Comment: Yeah @SecretLloyd! Here’s my most up to date code: df = df[“date”].strftime(“%Y-%m-%d”).strptime(“date”, “%-m/%-d/%Y”)

Comment: I meant you should put it in the question but that works!

Comment: I think your quotes are invalid. You should be using the ASCII quotation marks `""` or `''` - unicode quotation marks aren't recognized as string delimiters by most programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

This line will change the format "yyyy-mm-dd" to "mm/dd/yyyy"

```
df = df[5:7]+'/'+df[8:10]+'/'+df[0:4]
```